# Auto update code on server

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

I wanted to know if there is any setting in sublime that automatically update the code on the server. Meaning changing code on local desktop and getting changes on server automatically.

Comment: what server are you talking about specifically?

Comment: One of the following Sublime packages should do what you want. I would recommend wbond's SFTP, but note that it is not free (you can try it for free though): https://packagecontrol.io/search/ftp